# Continually increment a macro's value after calling another macro

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, armcc

I am writing a header file with a structured schema in mind. My goal is to define a base address that will increment after calling another macro. The purpose of this is to keep a running count of the new base address and to check at compile time whether or not it exceeds the maximum physical address.

I previously thought of using a global variable to count the address, but this would be resolved at run time and I require this during compile-time, before any binary is outputted so as to prevent possible memory corruption.

Here's what I mean by example:

The following is what I want the header file too look like upon inspection (or something equivalent):

```
#define DRAM_DEFINE_PTR              0x30000000
#define DRAM_DATA1_BASE              0x30000100
#define DRAM_DATA1_SIZE              0x050
#define DRAM_DATA2_SIZE              0x400
#define DRAM_DATA3_BASE              0x30000600
#define DRAM_DATA3_SIZE              0x300

#define DRAM_DEFINES(x,y)            (...) 
// store base 'x' and size 'y' in a structure and increment DRAM_DEFINE_PTR accordingly

1.     DRAM_DEFINES (DRAM_DATA1_BASE,        DRAM_DATA1_SIZE)
2.     DRAM_DEFINES (0x0,                    DRAM_DATA2_SIZE)   //base is previous base + size
3.     DRAM_DEFINES (DRAM_DATA3_BASE,        DRAM_DATA3_SIZE)
// more DRAM_DEFINES
```

In reality, the code block below will expand lines 1 and 2 to be:

```
1.     DRAM_DEFINES (0x30000100,        0x50)
       // DRAM_DEFINE_PTR now equals 0x30000150

2.     DRAM_DEFINES (0x30000150, 0x400)
       // DRAM_DEFINE_PTR now equals 0x30000550

3.     DRAM_DEFINES (0x30000600 , 0x300)
       // DRAM_DEFINE_PTR now equals 0x30000900
and so on
```

and then at the end of the file have an #error check to ensure we didn't go over the boundary

```
#if (DRAM_DEFINE_PTR > 0x40000000)
   #error "\nCAPACITY EXCEEDED by ", DRAM_DEFINE_PTR - 0x40000000, " bytes"
#endif
```

As we can see from above, not every region of memory is to be used completely. Like between 2 and 3 there is 50 bytes of buffer. So this means that base addresses can either be

- hard coded values using a #define OR
- offset from previous region's base + the previous region's size

Is this possible within the compiler I'm using (ARMCC RVCT 5.03)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the value of a macro in the course of translating one unit using the Boost Preprocessor library's [evaluated slots functionality](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/topics/evaluated_slots.html). It defines several "slots" that can be treated as mutable global variables by preprocessor code, which will let you add to a value as you go along, rather than permanently defining it with a single fixed expression. It's pure standard-compatible C (or C++).

The main syntactic nuisance is that you have to give the update operation two lines to itself, because it's powered by a `#define`/`#include` pair.

```
#define DRAM_PTR_SLOT 2    // any slot
#define DRAM_DEFINE_PTR BOOST_PP_SLOT(DRAM_PTR_SLOT)
#define SET_DRAM_DEFINE_PTR BOOST_PP_ASSIGN_SLOT(DRAM_PTR_SLOT)

#define BOOST_PP_VALUE 0x30000100 + 0x50
#include SET_DRAM_DEFINE_PTR    // DRAM_DEFINE_PTR now evals to 0x30000150

#define BOOST_PP_VALUE DRAM_DEFINE_PTR + 0x50
#include SET_DRAM_DEFINE_PTR    // DRAM_DEFINE_PTR now evals to 0x300001A0
```

It's not tremendously elegant - there's no way to pack a directive inside another macro, so you can't hide this inside a syntax like the one in the question - but you might be able to at least hide the Boost names under some domain-specific wrapper macros of your own.

Comment: Wow this is almost exactly what I was looking for, except for the directives part, but I hacked a way to accomplish that. Instead of using the '#' token to define the sub-directive, I use a nonsensical one, like '@@' which I then replace with '#' after running the CPP once. It's a bit hacky, but it works. Thanks for your help @Leushenko.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a global variable to store the address?

Comment: I considered this earlier, but the values would not be resolved until run-time and I require that check at compile time. For those curious , in my example you would "#define DRAM_DEFINE_PTR globalVar" and then perform arithmetic as needed within the macro.

Answer (score 0):

This likely cannot be done using the CPP as it was not designed with something like this in mind. I will be investigating the ARM assembler and it's macro capabilities to see if it can be used instead.